# Default model field Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've come from Django and was wondering how do I specify the default value of model if referenced just by calling it. Ie. <= @user %>

In Django, we can use in the model class;

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.fieldname
```

And it will use whatever field name or combined string we specify. Is this possible in rails?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Obligatory tip to new Rails developers: consider Haml instead of ERb. Much nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to define `to_s` in your model:

```
def to_s
  fieldname
end
```

Then in a view, you can do `<%= @user %>` and it'll output the `fieldname` you specify above.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the field you want, by implementing to_s method.